# Rabbitmq C# client timeout error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rabbitmq, timeoutexception

The following is part of a Rabbitmq consumer application that's built as a windows form in visual studio 2013. This form connects to an exchange that was set up in another program and listens for messages sent through one of three routing keys: "info", "error", and "warning". The user chooses which of those routing keys they would like to listen to by checking them on the windows form and then clicking the listen button.

```
private void listenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare("direct_logs", "direct");

            var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

            if (infoCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                channel.QueueBind(queueName, "direct_logs", "info");
            }
            if (errorCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                channel.QueueBind(queueName, "direct_logs", "error");
            }
            if (warningCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                channel.QueueBind(queueName, "direct_logs", "warning");
            }

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                messageTextBox.Text += "\n" + message;
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
        }
    }
```

In order to be able to perform the method QueueBind, however, I need queueName. But the program always fails on the line `var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;`. It always freezes for about 10 seconds and then comes up with a timeout exception. I had almost the exact same code work in a console application. Is there something different that I need to account for when using a windows form? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I looked again at the console application that worked and the main difference was that the exchange was a fannout exchange called "logs". So maybe a direct exchange doesn't let you get the queue name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're always having RabbitMQ time out on a `QueueDeclare`, you might just have memory issues with a long-running job. As suggested in this [google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/iZWokxvhlaU), try running:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_diagnostics:maybe_stuck().'
```

This tool just checks if there are any jobs that haven't had any stack trace changes within a certain time window, but can be useful for finding hanging jobs. If something is amiss, you'll get output like:

```
2017-03-27 13:59:27 There are 269 processes.
2017-03-27 13:59:27 Investigated 9 processes this round, 5000ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:28 Investigated 9 processes this round, 4500ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:29 Investigated 9 processes this round, 4000ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:29 Investigated 9 processes this round, 3500ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:30 Investigated 9 processes this round, 3000ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:30 Investigated 9 processes this round, 2500ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:31 Investigated 9 processes this round, 2000ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:31 Investigated 9 processes this round, 1500ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:32 Investigated 9 processes this round, 1000ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:32 Investigated 9 processes this round, 500ms to go.
2017-03-27 13:59:33 Found 9 suspicious processes.
2017-03-27 13:59:33 [{pid,<10469.54.0>},
                     {registered_name,user},
                     {current_stacktrace,
                         [{user,get_chars,8,[{file,"user.erl"},{line,613}]},
                          {user,do_io_request,5,
                              [{file,"user.erl"},{line,183}]},
                          {user,server_loop,2,[{file,"user.erl"},
etc
```

I've usually been sucessful in cleaning up suspicious jobs with just a `rabbitmqctl stop_app` and `rabbitmqctl start_app`, but you can also kill specific jobs using

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'erlang:exit(c:pid(0,54,0),kill).'
```